# OSGi bundle - get DataSourcePool for use in servlet in Adobe CQ5

Tags: java, osgi, datasource, aem

I'm trying to get DataSourcePool instance for servlet in OSGi in Adobe CQ5 bundle but the standard approach doesn't work. I used to get DataSourcePool via Activator like this

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
    private DataSourcePool source;

    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        ServiceReference dspRef = context.getServiceReference(DataSourcePool.class.getName());
        source = (DataSourcePool)context.getService(dspRef);
    }

    public static DataSourcePool getDataSourcePool(){
        return source;
    }
}
```

but since I started to develop in Eclipse, this doesn't work anymore. I have this project structure in Eclipse

```
project-default
project-default-bundle
\src
   \main
       \java
          \cz
             \package
                \sub1
                \sub2
                \Activator.java
           \other
              \package
                 \servlets
                    \MyServlet.java

project-default-components
project-default-content
```

When I try to get the DataSourcePool in MyServlet.java, the return value from cz.package.Activator.getDataSourcePool(); is null. I also tried to use @Reference but it just gives me HTTP 403 Forbidden error after compiling and running the servlet.

Thanks for any help

**EDIT**

This is what my servlet looks like

```
package my.pckg.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.day.commons.datasource.poolservice.DataSourcePool;

@Component(immediate = true)
@Service(value=javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties(value={
        @Property(name="sling.servlet.methods", value={"GET"}),
        @Property(name="sling.servlet.paths", value={"/myservices/saveandinvite"})
})
public class SaveAndInvitePeople extends SlingAllMethodsServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7923689671005539630L;
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SaveAndInvitePeople.class);

    @Reference
    private DataSourcePool source;
    //private DataSourcePool dataSourcePool = null;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{
        log.info("doGet");
        /*this.dataSourcePool = Activator.getDataSourcePool();
        if(this.dataSourcePool == null){
            log.info("datasourcepool == null!");
        }*/
        if(this.source == null){
            log.info("datasourcepool == null!");
        }
        try{
            //DataSource ds = (DataSource)this.dataSourcePool.getDataSource("myConnection");
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)this.source.getDataSource("myConnection");
            if(ds == null){
                log.error("DataSource is null!");
                return;
            }
            log.info("datasource not null! gonna try to get connection!");
            Connection con = null;
            try{
                con = ds.getConnection();
            }catch(Exception e){
                log.error("Exception "+e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            }finally{
                if(con != null){
                    try{
                        con.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        log.error("Exception "+e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            log.info("looks OK!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Exception "+e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException{

    }
}
```

And this is the HTTP 403 Forbidden message I get.

```
Forbidden

Cannot serve request to /myservice/saveandinvite/ in org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

Request Progress:

      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/myservice/saveandinvite/
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/myservice/saveandinvite/ resolves to Resource=, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite, resource=[SyntheticResource, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite]
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/myservice/saveandinvite', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='/'
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      0 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite, resource=[SyntheticResource, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite])}
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{2,resolveServlet(, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite, resource=[SyntheticResource, type=sling:syntheticResourceProviderResource, path=/myservice/saveandinvite])} Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{2,ServletResolution} URI=/myservice/saveandinvite/ handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: cz.devsoft.hartmann.project20130901v01.impl.filters.LoggingFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG RedirectFilter did not redirect (request extension does not match)
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Applying Componentfilters
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet#0}
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Using org.apache.sling.servlets.get.impl.helpers.StreamRendererServlet to render for extension=null
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Applying Error filters
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter
      2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_START{handleError:status=403}
      6 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{4,handleError:status=403} Using handler /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/default.jsp
     22 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) LOG Found processor for post processing ProcessorConfiguration: {contentTypes=[text/html],order=-1, active=true, valid=true, processErrorResponse=true, pipeline=(generator=Config(type=htmlparser, config={}), transformers=(Config(type=linkchecker, config={}), Config(type=mobile, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@49f984de), Config(type=mobiledebug, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@1c8230c3), Config(type=contentsync, config=org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.JcrPropertyMap@274f60d4), serializer=Config(type=htmlwriter, config={}))}
     23 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{23,Request Processing} Dumping SlingRequestProgressTracker Entries
ApacheSling/2.2 (Day-Servlet-Engine/4.1.42, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.7.0_51, Linux 2.6.32-431.3.1.el6.x86_64 amd64)
```

I tried to check logs but there is nothing(just info message that /favicon.ico couldn't be found)

**EDIT2**
When I change the request to POST and the servlet to handle POST requests, the error msg changes to HTTP 500

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Resource at '/myservices/saveandinvite' is not modifiable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a start ordering issue. You assume that the service is already available and registered before your bundle starts, but that assumption is unsafe (and in fact the null shows it to be untrue).

You should use Declarative Services with the @Reference annotation. I don't understand why you say this leads to an HTTP Forbidden error... there is no connection between these things.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. Check edit in my question - I've added my servlet code and the HTTP 403 message.

Comment: The error about POST makes sense because you have only listed GET as the allowed method in the service properties. Unfortunately for the 403 forbidden error, I don't know enough about Sling to help. It's probably something to do with the configuration of the HTTP engine, but somebody else will have to take it from here. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it appears your servlet isn't resolved and when you hit the path in URL - 
For 'GET' request DefaultGetServlet is invoked

> 2 (2014-01-29 11:51:40) TIMER_END{2,ServletResolution} URI=/myservice/saveandinvite/ handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet

For 'POST' request SlingPostServlet is invoked

> This will never work as the path for your servlet is non existent and no data can be saved at that location.

To verify your path actually resolved to servlet, you can check if the path resolves to servlet by going to `/system/console/servletresolver`

To start with goto `/system/console/components` and search for your servlet and check the status. If its not Active, expand the component for details and check that all references are satisfied.

You could tail your logs and try activating the component and check if there are any errors generated and proceed accordingly to fix those. 
Share your error logs here in case you need further help. 
There will be errors in logs on reactivating the component which you don't see while calling the servlet path as they initially would get generated when your bundle is deployed.